# How many ways to pick pairs from a group of six?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many ways can we group six people into pairs?

I expect the answer to be  $6!/(2!)^3$ but the textbook gives the solution as  6!/(2!)<sup>3</sup>3!

I'm confused, as the way I got my answer was to do

(6 pick 2) * (4 pick 2) * (2 pick 2)

(6!)/(2!4!) * (4!/(2!2!))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $6!$ distinct ways to place $6$ items into six slots.  Consider the first two slots as the first pair, the second two slots as the second pair, and the last two slots as the last pair.  Within each pair there are $2!$ equivalent orders (e.g., $35$ is the same as $53$).  This is true for each of the three pairs, so we must divide by $(2!)^3$.

But you can also re-order the three pairs in $3!$ ways.  (That is, ${\bf 35}12{\bf 64}$ is the same as ${\bf 64}12{\bf 35}$, and so forth.)  Thus we must also divide by $3!$.

Thus the final number is:

$$\frac{6!}{2! 2! 2! 3!} = \frac{6!}{(2!)^3 3!}$$

Comment: Thanks! Is it pure coincidence that the number of ways to pair up 6 people is also equal to the number of ways to choose 2 people from a group of six (${6\choose 2}?